# error printing selected data

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
include 'dpconfig.php'; 
$id = $_SESSION['uid'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE first='$id'";

$check = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die ("err $id " . mysqli_error ($conn));

$check2 = mysqli_num_rows($check);

if ($check2 != 0) 

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($check))

$showid = $row[0];

 $showfirst = $row[1]; 

 $showlast = $row[2]; 

 $showuid = $row[3]; 

  echo  $showid;

  echo      $showfirst;

  echo       $showlast;

  echo       $showuid;

?>
```

The above code doesnt give me any error, so i think its ok, i cant get it to echo out on my website, i want it to echo out id, first name, last name, username..when i run this code it doesnt echo out anything and doesnt give any error. Thank you for helping.

Comment: assoc returns associative array not indexed array

Comment: Please, how can i correct that..

Comment: @AnnJoe anything from http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php ?

Comment: You don't know what's wrong because you don't check for errors in your code. Never assume the code is always going to work flawlessly. Use [`mysqli_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to get a detailed error message from the database.

Comment: Error reporting might be turned off you can try turning it on so that you can check what went wrong in case there was an error. You can put this `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1);` at the top and test it again. See this http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php. BTW I think you missed the braces on the while loop, that might be the cause as well.

Comment: @JohnConde they are `or die ("err $id " . mysqli_error ($conn))` they're just not telling us the whole story ;-) and leaving everyone down "that hole".

Comment: ok, I'm outta this (rabbit) hole.

Answer (score 0):

You are fetching the results as an associative array `$example->associateArray['name']`.

You want this:

`while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($check))`

That is because `mysql_fetch_array()` can fetch results by either its associate array or its numeric array as defined by the manual [1]

[1] http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: i changed it to mysqli fetch array and now am getting undefined variable..

Comment: Please guys am new to php and mysqli, but i need to get this done, please help me.. am begging you all..Pls

Comment: What are you getting when you do `die(var_dump($row));` at the very end of the file?